# How to handle image url properly in CakePHP + jQuery DivCorners plugin

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-plugins, cakephp-2.0

The problem is following: on the main page all images are displayed correctly on other pages images are missing because of wrong relative path.

In my javascript file I have several calls like this:

```
$("#header").dcCreate({
        imgPrefix: "img/b/h/",
        fileType: ".png",
        expand: 16,
        position: "outside"
    });
```

My first idea is to change `imgPrefix` so that it would point to the absolute url of the image. Are there any better ways?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#header").dcCreate({
        imgPrefix: "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/b/h/",
        fileType: ".png",
        expand: 16,
        position: "outside"
    });
```

or even

```
$("#header").dcCreate({
        imgPrefix: "<?php echo IMAGES; ?>b/h/",
        fileType: ".png",
        expand: 16,
        position: "outside"
    });
```

would make it slightly more portable. `$this->webroot` is the path to `APP/webroot`

`IMAGES` is a CakePHP defined constant pointing to `APP/webroot/img/`.

Comment: This doesn't work in .js file. I would not like to change the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't normally parsed inside `.js` files, as this would create all kinds of problems. What you could do is declare a JavaScript variable with the path to the images in your Cake layout before `$scripts_for_layout`. I believe Wordpress does something similar to correctly handle the URLs for AJAX request.

```
  <?php echo $this->Html->scriptBlock(sprintf('var IMAGE_PATH = "%s";', IMAGES)); ?>
```

In that case you can use `IMAGE_PATH` in your external JavaScript files which are normally printed as part of the `$scripts_for_layout` variable.

You could also declare a global variable in the external JavaScript file containing the absolute path to your images, if that's the only place where you need the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Following worked for me.

```
<?php $folder = $this->webroot; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
      var folderPath = '<?php echo $folder; ?>';

      $("#header").dcCreate({
        imgPrefix: folderPath  + "img/b/h/",
        fileType: ".png",
        expand: 16,
        position: "outside"
       });
 </script>
```